# Marketing Cloud SSL DIY Setup Cheaper?

Tags: marketing-cloud, security, ssl, sender-authentication-package

I'm a marketing cloud and ssl newbie, so forgive this newb question. So, we have 2 business units with SAP needing 4 SSL Certificate, I contacted our account exec to get a quote. The total was ($6.5k) for four SSL Certificate which is honestly quite expensive. So, I was wondering if there's a way to minimize this cost by possibly provisioning our own SSL Certificates? I couldnt find a guide somewhere to procure our own or DIY and send it to SF. If anybody ever went to the process, I would really appreciate a guide however brief.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though it's possible, I will discourage you from bringing your own SSLs for a number of reasons:

- You can only provide your own certificates for click/view/cloud page urls hosted on the SFMC platform, however, image urls must be secured via certificates obtained by SFMC (due to the nature of images being served by a CDN).
- You will still need to purchase the SSL SKU, and the price from Salesforce perspective will be the same.
- Your own certificates do not auto-renew, so you will need to keep track on certificate expiration, and provide new versions to Salesforce well ahead of expiration.

Comment: Thank you so much for this valuable information. This saves so much time and work. Kudos!

Comment: I thought the SSL SKU comes with 2 SSLs, so for full coverage you need to purchase 2x SKU for SSL.

Now, I'm seeing it's actually 4!?!  Was something changed?

Comment: @GeorgeRosedale the change from 2 to 4 SSLs has been introduced now that the SSL config finally has become self service within SFMC. I am still looking into details on why this high number of certs is needed.